# Web browser unable to read javascript etc.

Tags: javascript, html, flash, browser, components

i have build a basic and very simple web browser, it contains two features, the "go back" and "go forward" navigation tools, and of course the URL search field. And i'm happy with that, but, it can't read javascript or the necessary components for a "basic" browser. So i wonder if there is any kind of solution for my web browser so it can view pages and execute javascript features.
Flash player is not necessary, but if it's possible to make Flash work that would be great.
Any kind of answer is appreciated.

Comment: have you tested it in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a Javascript engine such as [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) or [v8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), unless you're feeling really courageous and want to build your own. There is documentation on each of those sites for how to integrate.

Comment: Thanks, i'm currently trying the Cobra engine, it looks good, but a little confusing. Btw, i'm writing it in java so v8 wont work.